# Why was the rye angry about being called "golden"?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection

From the poem "Somewhere Spring Approached" by Pavlo Tychnya:

> The rye ripened. I told her: "You're Golden!"
> Angrily her eyebrows splintered.
> She turned away. And left.
> And just kept looking back -
> As though she were calling out: "Come!"

It turns out that rye is planted over the fall, grown over the winter and harvested in early spring, so that much I understand. Also, from pictures of it, it does appear to be golden. That being said, why does the rye react "angrily" to that?